# Differential equation (comparison)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We are given a function $f(t,x)$ in $[0,\infty) \times \mathbb(R)$ .

For fixed $t$ , f(t,x) is non decreasing in terms of $x$ . 
And $g,h \in C^1([0,\infty)$ such that :

$h'(t)\leq f(t,h(t)) , t\geq 0$

$g'(t) =f(t,g(t)) , t\geq 0$

We want to show that if $h(0)<g(0)$ then $h(t)<g(t) , \forall t \geq 0$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3366874/115115 for a possible proof using other assumptions to ensure uniqueness of solutions. Using the exact solutions as level curves, one can explore how $h$ traverses these levels.

Comment: thanks . There is a typo in the original, I mean to say increasing and then it is easy