# Prove that a funcion with greater derivative is greater

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

Let $f,g\in C^1(I)$ where $I$ is a bounded open interval.

Let $x^*\in I$ and suppose that $g$ satisfy the equation $g'(x)=k\cdot g(x)^r$
and $f$ the inequality $f'(x)\geq k\cdot f(x)^r$ for all $x\geq x^*$. Where $k> 0$ and $r>1$.

I also have that $g(x^*)=f(x^*)>0$.

I'd like to show that $f(x)\geq g(x)\quad\forall x\geq x^*$ and I succeed when
$f'(x^*)>k\cdot f(x^*)^r$. But I don't know even if it's true when $f'(x^*)=k\cdot f(x^*)^r$.

Comment: See also [proof that $f(t)$ is less than or equal to $g(t)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3366874/115115) for a more general statement of this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differential (in)equalities together with $g(x^*)=f(x^*)>0$ imply that both $f$ and $g$ are increasing and therefore strictly positive for $x \ge x^*$. Therefore we can conclude that
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^r} \ge k = \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)^r}
$$
for $x \ge x^*$. Integrating this relation from $x^*$ to $x$ gives
$$
 \frac{1}{1-r} f(x)^{1-r} \ge \frac{1}{1-r} g(x)^{1-r} 
$$
and consequently $f(x) \ge g(x)$.