# Calculate maximal interval by bounding $f(t,x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider a system:
\begin{align}
x'&= f(t,x)\\
x(t_0) &= x_0
\end{align}
where we can assume $f$ is continuous and Lipschitz with respect to $x$, so we have existence and uniqueness of solutions.

Suppose we can bound $$|f(t,x)| \leq g(t,x)$$ at all points $(t,x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. We can assume $g(t,x)$ is also continuous and Lipschitz with respect to $x$.

Consider the solution $y_1$ to the problem:
\begin{align} 
y' &= g(t,y) \\
y(t_0) &= x_0
\end{align}
and $y_2$ solution to
\begin{align} 
y' &= -g(t,y) \\
y(t_0) &= x_0
\end{align}

Is is true that $$y_2(t) \leq x(t) \leq y_1(t)$$ for all $t > 0$ in which $y$ is defined? I would say it is true since $x$, $y$ are real functions which agree in a point and such that
$$y'_2(t) \leq x'(t) \leq y'_1(t)$$ In particular, if both $y_1$ and $y_2$ are defined in all $\mathbb{R}$ then $x$ is defined in all $\mathbb{R}$.

I have never seen this principle used in practice to determine maximal intervals of solutions, that's why I have doubts.

**Example**
Suppose we have the ODE:
$$x' = \ln(1+t^2) \cos(x) x = f(t,x)$$
with $x(1) = x_0$

Then we can bound $|f(t,x)|$ as:
$$ |f(t,x)| \leq |\ln(1+t^2) \cos(x) x| \leq |(1+t^2) x| $$

The solution to the ODE:
\begin{align} y' &= (1+t^2) y \\ y(1) = x_0
\end{align}
is $y_1 = x_1 e^\frac{t^3}{3+t}$
and the solution to the ODE $y' = -(1+t^2)y$ is $y_2 = x_1 e^{-\frac{t^3}{3+t}}$.

Can we deduce:
$$ x_1 e^{-\frac{t^3}{3+t}} \leq x(t) \leq x_1 e^{\frac{t^3}{3+t}}$$?

Comment: This is the very essence of the theory of the comparison principles. The answer to your question is yes, you may find explanations on Wikipedia. The Gronwall lemma is the easiest comparison principle, it deals with the linear case. With some work you can extend it to the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the solution curves $y(t)=\phi_+(t;t_0,y_0)$ of $y'=g(t,y)$. Then the inequality $f\le g$ tells you that at every point the vector field for $f$ crosses the curve of $\phi_+$ at that point downwards. Thus for any $y_0>x_0$, the solution $x(t)$ can not cross $\phi_+(t;t_0,y_0)$ for $t\ge 0$. In the limit, also $y_+(t)=\phi_+(t;t_0,x_0)$ is an upper bound.

One can also put this in formulas by considering $h(t)=\phi_+(t_0;t,x(t))$, going forward with $f$ and then backward with $g$, and computing its derivative using the derivation laws of the flow. This should give a falling function. See [Dynamical systems proof that $ f(t)$ is less than or equal to $g(t)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366874/dynamical-systems-proof)

The same goes for the lower bound, and also for negative times where the positions of $\phi_+$ and $\phi_-$ are switched.